# When web page is scrolled down, after header is fixed at top, the scroll bar will jump up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically What I am trying to do is to have a fixed header at top, when page is scrolled. please find the below code snip which i have used.

```
//This method is used to fixed header, while page is scrolling.
var fixedPageHeader = {
        fWScrolling : function () {
            var div = $('#headinfor');
            var start = $(div).offset().top;

            $.event.add(window, "scroll", function(){
                var p = $(window).scrollTop();
                if((p)>start){
                    $(div).css('position','fixed');
                    $(div).css('top', '0px');
                    $(div).css('left','0px');
                    $(div).css('margin-top','-2px'); 
                    $(div).css('z-index','500');
                }else{
                    $(div).css('position','static');
                    $(div).css('top','');
                    $(div).css('margin-top','0px'); 
                    $(div).css('z-index','0');
                }
            });
        }
 }
```

at the time header get fixed at top of the page, scroll bar is jumped to right back to start. i wont be able to scroll down the page.

Comment: I don't see an issue with that code. Can you create a jsfiddle to show an example of the problem?

Comment: Also, since you're using jQuery, you can golf your code like so: `$(div).css({ position:'fixed', top: '0px', left:'0px', margin-top:'-2px', z-index:'500' });`

Comment: Thank you philtune for your response. I'l try my best to replicate this issue at jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this issue is, when header gets fixed at top of the browser, its z-index will be assigned a value. So there will be space created between content and browser's top bar which is x (please check the image i have attached).Thereforr scroll bar suddenly jumps up.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1dp9jlk2GZMYU9iM3lST2xzSkk/view?usp=sharing

In order to get ride of that, need to create div with same hight as the header. when it gets fixed at top of the browser when scrolling down and hide it when scrollig up.